# how to use split and string builder together in groovy

Tags: string, groovy, split, stringbuilder

I would like to split the string using a comma and append another string with the split value.

For example, I have a string `make=apple,product=iPhone`. I want to split the string apple, iPhone which I'm doing below. After splitting I want to append another string in each splitted value. So my final string should look like this, `make=apple-Id=1234,product=iPhone-Id=1234.`

If I have a single string with no comma, then I would have to display `make=apple-Id=1234`

```
    def myString = "make=apple,product=iPhone"
    def result = myString.split(",")
    for( String values : result )
        println(values);
```

I'm able to split it, but struggling to append like how I want. Can someone suggest what's the right way of doing in groovy?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
def s='make=apple,product=iPhone'
println s.split(',').collect{it+'-Id=1234'}.join(',')
```

result:

```
make=apple-Id=1234,product=iPhone-Id=1234
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the [collect](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/docs/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/lang/Iterable.html#collect(groovy.lang.Closure)) method to transform each segment of the split String into what you need. Then you can combine them back together as a single String with the [join](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/docs/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/lang/Iterable.html#join(java.lang.String)) method.

```
def myString = "make=apple,product=iPhone"
def result = myString.split(',').collect { it + '-Id=1234' }.join(',')
assert result == 'make=apple-Id=1234,product=iPhone-Id=1234'
```